# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode, image

linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) 
duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

I don't know why I got that error even _dragView is not found in my project. I got that error when I used https://github.com/myang-git/iOS-Image-Crop-View in my project. Below image is error details.

[image]

Comment: Are you including "ImageCropView.h" anywhere? It seems you should include "ViewController.h" instead

Comment: @MargaretBloom I'm including "ImageCropView.h" because that's what I need to crop image.

Comment: Ok, Do you have the file *ViewController.m* in your project? If so, remove it (Along with *ViewController.h*). It should just be a sample.

Comment: @MargaretBloom same error even removed.

Comment: The error you posted explicitly show a duplicate symbol between *ImageCropView.m* and *ViewController.m*. If you removed *ViewController.m*, the error cannot be the same. Anyway I think you only need the files: *ImageCropView.h, ImageCropView.m* and the dir *FXBlurView*. Try cleaning your project.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I've already added those files into my projects. All are same error output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105229/discussion-between-margaret-bloom-and-ppshein).

Comment: Can you check which are the files where you are using ImageCropView. Also have you modified ImageCropView to include something ?

Comment: I didn't modify anything. Just added ImageCropView.h & .m and FXBlurView.h & .m into my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to comment out `UIView* dragView;`in file `ImageCropView.h` and check.

As such there is no use of dragView in ImageCropView anywhere and at my end sample code still works. Developer mush have forgotten to remove it.

Which I am assume somewhere in your code duplication is happening due to dragView property. Might be in xib or storyboard IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently face the same issue. I know **ppshein** got the answer but to help someone else who may suffer from the same issue I was in.

According to my application flow I am using printer related third party class to print. To use that I have created object of that class in both of my files `ImagePrintViewController` and `PrintResultViewController` separately and passed required data to it. 

In my scenario I am getting same error with variable name like `_printerSetup` in two of my files`/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../x86_64/ImagePrintViewController.o`
and `/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../x86_64/PrintResultViewController.o`.

I have search in both of my file for the above variable name. But I couldn't find that.

After searching long on this I got a idea to **delete reference** of my second file i.e. `BRPrintResultViewController.h` and `BRPrintResultViewController.m` after merging code in my first file.

With this I found my solution and my code runs fine after this.